# Validar informação vinda em req

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu recebo informações para minha rota, onde estão contidas dentro de um `req`. Ex:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res){

});
```

Essas informações colocarei no meu banco, porém, antes de inserir, tenho que verificar se realmente veio todas as informações, pois se não, haverá uma exceção pois tentaria inserir informações de campos que não existem.

Gostaria de saber como eu posso validar esse campos. Por exemplo, eu utilizo:

```
if (req.body['name']) {
     console.log('Nome foi enviado com sucesso!');
}
```

Porém fazer isso para todos os campos enviados torna as coisas mais difíceis, gostaria de saber se o NodeJs proporciona alguma forma mais fácil e eficiente de fazer isso.

Comment: Talvez isto ajude: https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: O que fazes no caso de não validar? envias de volta? Se queres fazer uma validação simples bastaria algo como `var valido = Object.keys(req.body).filter(k => !req.body[k]).length == 0;` (é um exemplo, certamente precisa de afinar, mas ficaria bem simples)

Comment: Boa, @ precisarei de algo parecido para validar email e telefone, essa biblioteca pode ajudar.

Comment: Sim @Sergio, se algum dado não chegar, enviarei um res.status(x); Eu sei que o front end certamente fará uma validação caso algum campo não tenha sido preenchido, além disso, se eu tentar inserir algo que não veio no banco, irá dar exceção, e o servidor cairá, para tornar mais seguro, por via das dúvidas, quero fazer também.

Comment: Boa, e deves. Se usares essa biblioteca e deres os nomes certos às chaves dos dados que passas podes simplificar muito a implementação. Pois podes usar num loop `validator.is[chave]('foo@bar.com');`

Comment: Pode colocar como resposta um exemplo de como ficaria com o loop utilizando essa biblioteca ? Como exemplo pode utilizar campos como `nome`,`telefone`,`email`,`endereço`. @Sergio

Comment: Complementando a dica do Miguel vc pode usar o [Express Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) que usa a lib validator por traz, mas que trabalha de forma um pouco mais integrada como express.